# How do I redirect a URL with special (%C2%A0) characters in Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I found out that I have link to one of URLs with some garbage behind that would generate some traffic, however whoever it placed it did it wrong:

```
/domain/sub-directory/%C2%A0
```

Therefore, I would like to redirect this URL to the one it was intended. However, I could not figure out how to do this properly.

I tried already:

```
location ^~ /sub-directory/(.*) { return 301 https://example.com/sub-directory/; }
```

and also

```
rewrite ^https://example.com/sub-directory/%C2%A0$ https://example.com/sub-directory/ permanent;
```

but none of them works. Any idea, how to fix this?

Comment: Try: `location ^~ /sub-directory/ { return 301 https://example.com/sub-directory/$request_uri; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent it as a hex value in a regular expression.

For example:

```
rewrite ^(/sub-directory/)\xC2\xA0$ $1 permanent;
```